# Nextjs router query parameters not logging

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to log the query parameter in a Nextjs project. I never see the value logged, but the value shows up on the page. Should I just ignore that the logs in `npm dev` dont show the query parameter or should I handle the case where it's undefined?

/pages/test/[test].js

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
import React from "react";

const Test = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const {test} = router.query;
    console.log(router.query); // {}
    console.log(test);  // undefined
    return <div>
        <h1>{test}</h1>
    </div>
};
export default Test;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need use useEffect with 2 dependencies:

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const Test = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [query, setQuery] = useState(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
      setQuery(router.query)
      if (query){
        console.log(query); 
        console.log(query.test);
      } 
    },[router,query])
    
    return <div>
        <h1>{query && query.test}</h1>
    </div>
};
export default Test;
```

or with one dependency:

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

const Test = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(()=>{
      if (router.query){
        console.log(router.query); 
        console.log(router.query.test);
      } 
    },[router])
    
    return <div>
        <h1>{router && router.query && router.query.test}</h1>
    </div>
};
export default Test;
```

When you use useEffect you are sure the router has been tuned already.